# Automate clear of mysql database in drush site install

Tags: database, drush

Is is possible to automate clearing the database when I run site install?
e.g. here is my drush command:

```
drush si geoslate --db-url='mysql://root:root@localhost/geo_test' --site-name=Geoslate
```

But the db has to be cleared first. Can I automate this process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Chapabu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3119/chapabu) is correct, but if you're using drush 5.7, this is unnecessary with site-install. If there's an existing db, drush will warn you it will drop all tables in the existing database.

For example:

```
drush dl drupal --drupal-project-rename=test
cd test
% drush site-install standard --db-url=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/test --site-name=test
You are about to create a sites/default/files directory and create a sites/default/settings.php file and DROP all tables in your 'test' database. Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
No tables to drop.                                                                          [ok]
Starting Drupal installation. This takes a few seconds ...                                  [ok]
Installation complete.  User name: admin  User password: 6SkT989sPX
```

So let's rerun the site-install command over the now existing "test" directory

```
% drush site-install standard --db-url=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/test --site-name=test         130 ↵
You are about to DROP all tables in your 'test' database. Do you want to continue? (y/n):
```

Comment: Neat - I didn't realise it did this (It's been a while since I've used `site-install`) :-)

Comment: this is true but I am getting the error anyway, sh: mysql: command not found which is a separate problem due to the location of mysql

Comment: That should be something we can address. Can you describe how your hosting your drupal installation? Is it on a shared Hosting like HotDrupal.com, a local development stack, or…?

Answer (score 6):

If by *cleared*, you mean *drop all tables*, then you can use `drush sql-drop`

> Drop all tables in a given database.

[Official documentation for sql-drop](http://drush.ws/#sql-drop)

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error: sh: mysql: command not found . Any idea what might be causing this...

Comment: Try look over [here](http://495west.com/post/4895753657/bash-mysql-command-not-found) :)